# NSURLRequest not being sent?

Tags: json, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have a JSON request that gets sent to a server based on the response of another JSON request, I used this method to check what NSURL connection is being used to handle the response:

```
    if(connection == connection1) {
    // Connection 1
    } else if(connection == connection2) {
    // Connection 2
    }
```

It works for the first connection, which is sent out like this:

```
    NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/flight/status/%@/%@/dep/%@?appId=%@&appKey=%@&utc=false",airline.text,flightnumber.text,datestring,flightAPIIDstring,flightAPIkeystring];
    NSURL *jsonurl = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonStr];
    flightTrackJSONconnectionrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonurl];
    flighttrackJSONconnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                initWithRequest:flightTrackJSONconnectionrequest delegate:self];
    if(flighttrackJSONconnection){
    jsonresponse = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    } else {
    }
```

However, on the connectionDidFinishLoading for my first connection (flighttrackJSONconnection), when I use this code, the request for the 2nd connection is not sent out at all:

```
    NSString *departjsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/iata/%@?appId=%@&appKey=%@",DepartACode,flightAPIIDstring,flightAPIkeystring];
    NSURL *departjsonurl = [NSURL URLWithString:departjsonStr];
    departairportcheckJSONconnection = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:departjsonurl];
    departairportcheckJSONconnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                           initWithRequest:departairportcheckJSONconnectionrequest delegate:self];
    if(departairportcheckJSONconnection){
    departairportlookup = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    } else {
    }
```

I added NSLog checks to the connection didFailWithError, connection didReceiveResponse and connectionDidReciveData all to find that the only NSURL request going out was my flighttrackJSONconnection request...

So I'm wondering, did I miss something in my code, or is it simply not possible to send another NSURLRequest when it calls connectionDidFinishLoading?

Sorry if I seem like a noob, I'm just confused a bit...

Also, all the JSON parsing code (at least for the flighttrackJSONresponse connection) and such works fine on connectionDidFinishLoading, so its not like I made a mistake declaring anything & if it makes any difference, I'm trying to send 2 requests on the connectionDidFinishLoading, each of them with their own NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest names declared on the .h, I have the same issue with both.

Thanks for any tips or ideas guys..

Comment: Do you send the second connection based in a parameter of the fisrt json response?

Comment: Yeah I did, is that what might be the problem?

Comment: I posted an answer (as a suggestion). Check it out!

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling [flighttrackJSONconnection start] method and still the request goes?

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that doesn't work is the actual request, I didn't show the code, but before the request is sent it pulls an API key from a server, I tested it and the API key gets pulled fine, the only issue is it doesn't want to send the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the method `sendAsynchronousConnection`, like this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

    // Treat your response here
}];
```

Inside the block you treat your response. Parse your JSON, check what need to be done and call this same method inside it! Using this, you don't need to implement delegate methods.

Comment: So I would use that instead of calling (void)connectionDidFinishLoading?

Comment: Yes, instead of `[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:flightTrackJSONconnectionrequest delegate:self];`, use the method I wrote before and inside the completion block, call you second connection according to what you parse from you json.

Comment: Here is what I did: http://pastebin.com/0885RZtG thanks so much for the help by the way.

Comment: Did it work fine? Put inside the completion block a log to check the response `NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data])`

Comment: I'm getting: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' :/

Comment: Did you debug it? Can you make sure that the url you're requesting is returning something?

Comment: How did you fix it!! I am getting it when there is not internet.